# Multiplying nested dictionary value with another dictionary value

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries of which one is nested.

```
 grocery_list = {"Jane" : {"Oranges": 2 , "Cucumbers" : 2, "Onions": 5 , 
 "Tomatoes" : 4} , "Steve" : {"Oranges": 5 , "Cucumbers" : 4, "Onions": 6 
 }, "John" : {"Oranges": 8 , "Cucumbers" : 10, "Tomatoes" : 9}}

 price_list = {"Oranges" : .89, "Cucumbers" : 0.50 , "Onions": 2.00 , 
 "Tomatoes" : 1.00}
```

How do I create the output {User: (stock * price)} using the user name as input

I understand there are multiply ways to do this.  From what I gathered online, dictionary comprehension or for in loops may work, but I can seem to calculate the nested stock value in grocery_list with the value from the price_list

Expected results should be:

```
function(User)

Output {Jane:16.78}
```

Comment: Make a try at it. Spend some time with [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does it:

```
 grocery_list = {"Jane" : {"Oranges": 2 , "Cucumbers" : 2, "Onions": 5 , 
 "Tomatoes" : 4} , "Steve" : {"Oranges": 5 , "Cucumbers" : 4, "Onions": 6 
 }, "John" : {"Oranges": 8 , "Cucumbers" : 10, "Tomatoes" : 9}}

 price_list = {"Oranges" : .89, "Cucumbers" : 0.50 , "Onions": 2.00 , 
 "Tomatoes" : 1.00}




def get_total(User):
    user=grocery_list[User]
    total={User:sum({k:(user[k]*price_list[k]) for k in user.keys()}.values())}
    return total

get_total('Jane')
```

Output:

```
{'Jane': 16.78}
```

Let me know if there's any doubts

Comment: This produced the desired outcome and is the easiest to understand

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the subscript operator to get the user's grocery list, and then sum a generator expression that replaces the product name with its price and multiplies it by the amount:

```
def sumUser(user):
    return {user : sum((price_list[p] * a for (p, a) in grocery_list[user].items()))}
```

Comment: This is a more "pythonic" way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{user: sum([v*price_list[k] for k, v in purchase.items()]) for user, purchase in grocery_list.items()}
```

OUTPUT:

```
# Result: {'Jane': 16.78, 'Steve': 18.45, 'John': 21.12} #
```

Comment: I missed the part where you were asking to pass the user as input. Although on the new dict you can now do dict_name[user] or dict_name.get(user, None) to access the total price per user.